# Making an OAuth2 call from a Website to an API to another API

Tags: http, oauth-2.0, authorization, azure-active-directory

If I have a website making a request to API 1 which wants to make a call to a second API 2 like so:

> Website -> API 1 -> API 2

Can I simply take the contents of the Authorization HTTP header from the API 1 request and pass that into the request to API 2? My OAuth2 provider is Azure AD and I'm using delegated permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be following the 'on-behalf-of' flow to exchange your token with:

`client = website and resource = API 1` for a token with

`client = API 1 and Resource = API 2`

Read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios).

> If the web API needs to call another downstream web API, it can use the on-behalf-of flow to delegate the user’s identity and authenticate to the second-tier web API.

> Delegated User Identity with OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of Draft Specification
>
> The flow discussed below assumes that a user has been authenticated on another application (such as a native application), and their user identity has been used to acquire an access token to the first-tier web API.
>
> 1. The native application sends the access token to the first-tier web API.
> 2. The first-tier web API sends a request to Azure AD’s token endpoint, providing its Application ID and credentials, as well as the user’s access token. In addition, the request is sent with an on_behalf_of parameter that indicates the web API is requesting new tokens to call a downstream web API on behalf of the original user.
> 3. Azure AD verifies that the first-tier web API has permissions to access the second-tier web API and validates the request, returning a JWT access token and a JWT refresh token to the first-tier web API.
> 4. Over HTTPS, the first-tier web API then calls the second-tier web API by appending the token string in the Authorization header in the request. The first-tier web API can continue to call the second-tier web API as long as the access token and refresh tokens are valid.

A sample integrating this flow can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof).